# PHP register issues

Tags: php, post, methods

I'd like to know if there are any errors/exploits in this piece of coding, and also can someone help me because I register but it doesn't insert data into the database. If there are any mistakes can you correct them please. I want it so if the username exists, redirect them to error?=1, and so on with passwords not matching. Any help is appreciated.

Register.php

```
 <form action="register_acc.php" method="post">
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="input" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" maxlength="25" /><br />
                                <br />
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="input" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" /><br />
                                <br />
                            <input type="password" name="password2" class="input" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password again" maxlength="20" /><br />
                                <br />
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="input" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" maxlength="255" /><br />
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit "class="submit" value="Sign up">
                        </form>
```

register_acc.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
     include 'site/inc/config.php';

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$pass_conf = md5($_POST['password2']);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date= date("d-m-Y");


$q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'";
$r = mysql_query($q);

if (empty($username)) {
    header("Location: register.php?error=1");
        exit;
}

if ($password != $pass_conf) {
    header("Location: /site/register.php?error=2"); 
        exit;
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: /site/register.php?error=3"); 
        exit;
} 

if  (mysql_num_rows($r) == 0) {
    // Continue w/ registration, username is available!
    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (id, username, password, email, ip, rank, reg_date)
    VALUES (0, '$username', '$password', '$email', '$ip', 1, '$date'())";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    header("Location: /site/register.php?succsess=1"); 

}
          }
         else {
    header("Location: register.php?error=4");
           }
      ?>
```

Comment: Why you insert like this: $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (id, ...)
    VALUES (0, ...)";
You can ommit inserting id if is set to auto_increment in database

Also, yo have another error int he insert: VALUES (..., '$date'()), you don't need "()" after '$date'

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and in new code you should use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead

Comment: Thanks for your help, updated it
@Kingkero can you patch the exploits or tell me where they are, and also I'm going to switch to MySQLi soon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't concatenate the $username variable into the query.
Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '".$username."'"
```

Also your INSERT query looks a bit weird with the date() function. Try this:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
"INSERT INTO `users` (id, username, password, email, ip, rank, reg_date)
    VALUES (0, '$username', '$password', '$email', '$ip', 1, '".$date."')"
```

EDIT: SCRIPT EXAMPLE

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['username'])||!isset($_POST['email'])||!isset($_POST['password']))//enter more values if necessary
{
header("Location: error_page.php?error=1");
}
else
{
//do whatever, eg execute query
}
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\register_acc.php on line 17
Error occurs then

Comment: nvm I forgot the semi colon + it still doesnt put the data into the database.

Comment: did you change the query? because I edited it and the semi-colon issue wouldn't cause the parse error

Comment: I used your query, and I tried echos at specific parts of the coding and it doesn't show.
http://pastebin.com/E2D6njp8 my updated php code

Comment: try echoing the query and comment the result

Comment: @imulsion , OP's SELECT and INSERT statements are correct.just `()` after `'$date'` is incorrect. should i voted down ?

Comment: the likelihood is that the $username variable is not set. $_POST['submit'] is not set, meaning the query is never executed. try if(isset($_POST['username'] instead

Comment: @Amir no, the first query expects username to be $username, not the variable $username

Comment: I cant seem to hack it, any help :/? I just need a simple script where if username/password/password2/email is empty redirect them to a error page. Thanks

Comment: @ElizabethEdge I will edit with a simple script example to test for empty fields

Comment: @ElizabethEdge if it works, please consider accepting my answer. im happy to help. by the way, welcome to SO!

Comment: This is my updated code
http://pastebin.com/9aaNWZMm
Still doesn't enter data in db

Comment: @ElizabethEdge try without the concatenation so VALUES ('$username',//etc.

Comment: @ElizabethEdge put backticks around column names: `(\`id\`, \`username\`, \`password\`, \`email\`, \`ip\`, \`rank\`, \`reg_date\`)`